# TAFFYdb: Passing in options to a function

Tags: javascript, taffydb

***update:** This code is bonkers. The root of the issue here is recreating the name of a variable by concating strings and assuming it would then **magically turn into** that variable.. I had a lot to learn. Also, a much better way to pass an ambiguous number of options into a function is to use JSON.*

```
var availableTimes,
    selected_unit,
    selected_unit_number;

function createTimePicker(machineNumber){
    availableTimes = machineNumber({booked:"no"}).select("time");
    for (i=0;i<availableTimes.length;i++){
        $('<option/>').val(availableTimes[i]).html(availableTimes[i]).appendTo('#signin_start_time');
    }
}

$(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '#cybex_arctrainer_button', function() {
        selected_unit = "cybex_arctrainer";
    });

    $('body').on('change', '#signin_unit_number_selector', function () {
        selected_unit_number = $("#signin_unit_number_selector option:selected").text();
        unit_plus_number = selected_unit+selected_unit_number;
        createTimePicker(unit_plus_number);
    });
});
```

A few things: The database works. If I run `createTimePicker(cybex_arctrainer1)` it fills in the `availableTimes` variable just fine. The problem seems to be with combining `selected_unit+selected_unit_number` and passing them to `createTimePicker`.

Comment: machineNumber is called in createTimePicker() as though it's a function, but you pass two concated vars, which can never be a function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
machineNumber({booked:"no"})
```

`machineNumber` is a string, but you're trying to call it as if it is a function. You'll get the same error if you do something like

```
someVar = 'bob';
someVar();
```

You say that if you run

```
createTimePicker(cybex_arctrainer1);
```

but your code is not calling `createTimePicker` with *the variable* `cybex_arctrainer1` as an argument, instead it's doing something more like:

```
createTimePicker('cybex_arctrainer1');
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense. As I can see it, the only solution is to define functions for each variable call to `createTimePicker`. Is there no elegant way to implement this?

Comment: For anyone trying to pass variables into a function calling TAFFYdb, the trick is to use javascript objects. Calling the database has to be written out verbatim (as explained above); but the rows, columns, and inputs can be passed as objects.