# taffyDB select insert

Tags: javascript, jquery, taffydb

As you can see most of my example is in this 1 page but would like different pages with different data and drop down data but at the moment the drop down is on alert which is about as far as I got if it could change the filtering in the table somehow without writing to much extra data that be nice

at moment I use Javascript, taffydb, slimbox2 (for picture(s) gallery, which is not in this example as it works fine in the project am doing, that why I just use [image] instead of putting code for that) and jquery (1.3) [which is mainly for slimbox2], I like to keep the code low (that why jquery is a low version, but don't mind going higher if it helps me do my required task) so easier to load when I decide to upload the real project am working on, at the moment it just on my computer locally hope this code below helps but doesn't represent the project am trying to do.

Get a Error or wont load when I use

```
<script src="https://raw.github.com/typicaljoe/taffydb/master/taffy-min.js" type='text/plain'></script>
```

as taffy file to load so have to use local taffy even though it the same, but prefer having my own anyway

Found [This](http://www.jpenterprises.com/blog/2013/09/front-end-database-javascript-and-taffydb) but doesn't really do what I want and is confusing also uses xml and has 2 joining connecting drop down, while I want 1-3 separate single ones.
[Also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17933213/taffydb-passing-in-options-to-a-function) another example but it don't show the full page code just part

index.html page

```
<!DOCTYPE><head><title>Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
<script src="taffy.js"></script>
<script src="index1.js"></script>
<script src="index2.js"></script>

</head><form name="f">
<script>filter1 ();filter2 ();filter3 (); /*different filter(s) on different page(s)*/
table({country:"UK"/*filter1*/,area:1/*filter2*/,food:{has:"Pizza"}/*filter3*/});

</script></form>
```

style.css

```
table {width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;}
body,table,tr,td,th {text-align:center;}
```

In index1.js page, maybe make function filter1, filter2, filter3 and/or function Item1, Item2, Item3 (if possiable somehow to be nicer code)

```
var HR="<tr><td colspan='2'><hr style='width:90%;border:1px solid #000;'>";

function filter1 ()
{document.write("<SELECT NAME='s1' onChange='Item1 ()'>\
<OPTION VALUE='' selected>Country</OPTION>");
country().order('name').each(function (O1) {document.write("<OPTION VALUE='{country:"+O1.name+"}'>"+O1.name+"</OPTION>")});
document.write("</SELECT>");}

function filter2 ()
{document.write("<SELECT NAME='s2' onChange='Item2 ()'>\
<OPTION VALUE='' selected>Area</OPTION>");
area().order('name').each(function (O2) {document.write("<OPTION VALUE='{area:"+O2.name+"}'>"+O2.name+"</OPTION>")});
document.write("</SELECT>");}

function filter3 ()
{document.write("<SELECT NAME='s3' onChange='Item3 ()'>\
<OPTION VALUE='' selected>Food</OPTION>");
food().order('name').each(function (O3) {document.write("<OPTION VALUE='{Food:{has:"+O3.name+"}'>"+O3.name+"</OPTION>")});
document.write("</SELECT>");}

function Item1 ()
{for (i = 0; i < document.f.s1.length; i++) {if (document.f.s1[i].selected) {
chosen = document.f.s1[i].value}}if (chosen==0) {return false;} 
alert(chosen);}

function Item2 ()
{for (i = 0; i < document.f.s2.length; i++) {if (document.f.s2[i].selected) {
chosen = document.f.s2[i].value}}if (chosen==0) {return false;} 
alert(chosen);}

function Item3 ()
{for (i = 0; i < document.f.s3.length; i++) {if (document.f.s3[i].selected) {
chosen = document.f.s3[i].value}}if (chosen==0) {return false;} 
alert(chosen);}

function table (tf) {TF=people().filter(tf);if(TF.count()>=1){document.write("<table>"+HR);TF.each(
function(t){country=t.country;area=t.area;name=t.name;food=t.food;document.write("<tr><td>[image]<td><table border='1' \
bordercolor='#000'><tr><td width='50%'><b>Country:</b>"+country+" <b>Area:</b>"+area+"<td width='50%'><b>Name:</b>"+
name+"<tr><td colspan='2'><b>Fav Food(s):</b> "+food.join(" - ")+"</table>"+HR)});document.write("</table>");}}
```

in index2.js

```
var people=TAFFY();var country=TAFFY();var area=TAFFY();var food=TAFFY(); /*ECT*/
country.insert({name:"UK"});country.insert({name:"USA"}); /*ECT*/
area.insert({name:1});area.insert({name:2}); /*ECT*/
food.insert({name:"Pizza"});food.insert({name:"Chocolate"});food.insert({name:"Cheeseburger"});
food.insert({name:"Cheese"});food.insert({name:"Fruits"});food.insert({name:"Pasta"}); /*ECT*/

country().each(function (script) {document.write("<script src='"+script.name+".js'></script>")});
```

in UK.js file

```
people.insert({country:"UK",name:"Mark",area:1,food:["Pizza","Chocolate"]});
people.insert({country:"UK",name:"Mark",area:1,food:["Pizza","Pasta"]});
people.insert({country:"UK",name:"Mary",area:1,food:["Pasta"]});
people.insert({country:"UK",name:"John",area:2,food:["Pizza","Chocolate","Pasta"]});
people.insert({country:"UK",name:"Matthew",area:2,food:["Cheeseburger"]});
//ECT
```

in USA.js file

```
people.insert({country:"USA",name:"Luck",area:1,food:["Pizza","Cheese"]});
people.insert({country:"USA",name:"Luck",area:1,food:["Pizza","Chocolate"]});
people.insert({country:"USA",name:"Lucy",area:1,food:["Pasta","Fruits"]});
people.insert({country:"USA",name:"Adam",area:2,food:["Pizza","Chocolate","Pasta","Cheeseburger"]});
people.insert({country:"USA",name:"Anna",area:2,food:["Fruits","Cheese"]});
//ECT
```

I know I could just filter by using normal text but I will insert table into different pages that will have differnt
filer1 and/or filter2 and/or filter3 or I might have 1 filter just using text while the other 1 and/or 2 depenedent 
of dropdown and maybe 1-2 page(s) with all 3 filters depenedent of dropdown

Comment: So where is the question again? If you edit your question to briefly summarize the problem at the end, that might help the readers who want to help.

Comment: yeah it is quite confusing sorry,  the main question is how do I use drop down to filter stuff already loaded on to a page, can I use 1 or more to filter more using more then 1 drop down

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/Bmpt9Dg6oGzAWe2UhKWw?p=preview hope this is a better example of what am trying to do